# Flow - Get records with OR condition

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow and a Get Records element. Assuming there is a "Record type" (or a similar filtering field) for the object, is there a way to get records of multiple types using a single Get Records element?

Basically, what I wish is to get records of type "A" OR type "B" using a single Get Records element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that OR can be achieved by using the same filter criteria:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_data_get.htm&type=5

> When you define multiple filters, the filter logic usually defaults to AND. However, if multiple filters have the same field selected and use the equals operator, the filters are combined with OR.
>
> For example, your filters check whether a case’s Type equals Problem (1), Type equals Feature Request (2), and Escalated equals true (3). At run time, the filters are combined to (1 OR 2) AND 3.